# Split throught % of Open Rate

Tags: trigger, journeybuilder, query, sql, code

I have a journey where I send a 1st email and after that email I have to evaluate the opening % of that 1st email. In one way I will send another email to everyone who has an open rate > 20% and another way where the open rate is < 20% of the first email.

What's the best way to do this?
Through SQL query?! with open rate rule?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Each subscriber would have an open rate of either 0% (they didn't open) or 100% (they did open the email). Are you trying to evaluate every subscriber's open rate across all emails, not just based on the first email in your journey?

Comment: After sending a first email I want to assess that >20% opened and <20% did not open that first email. For those >20% I send a 2nd email and for those <20% I send another email. There are different paths and emails for each, taking into account the opening rate of the 1st email for everyone.